# How to backup with s3cmd, ignoring multiple directories and file types

Tags: s3cmd

I've been trying to figure out how to backup the contents of my file server's (CentOS via smb) user's folder, ignoring certain file types and directories. It seems like this should be easy, but I'm not getting anywhere on figuring out how to ignore multiple directories.

I'd like to ignore the following:

- all files and directories starting with a `.` or a `_`
- all MS Office temp files (eg `~$*`)
- lock files (eg `.lock`)

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of the `--exclude` flag, but can't get any to work right.

This is the command that makes the most sense, but it's not excluding anything:

```
s3cmd sync --dry-run --verbose --delete-removed --exclude '.*' '_*' '~$*' '*.lock' /home/user-folder s3://bucket-name/
```

Comment: I'm interested in skipping .ts files. I'll take a look

Answer (score 13):

If you are already using `.gitignore`, you can do something like

```
s3cmd sync --exclude '.git/*' --exclude-from .gitignore <local_dir> s3://<bucket>/
```

as stated in [this blog post](http://easyart.github.io/2012/04/17/deploying-static-assets-to-s3-using-s3cmd/) and confirmed by the documentation for `--exclude-from` from the [official docs](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync) (Ctrl+F and search for "exclude-from").

It works great, with one minor drawback: if you're excluding a folder within `.gitignore`, you must exclude its contents also, or `s3cmd` will grab its contents. However, this is easy, you can just add a line like `<foldername>/*` inside the `.gitignore` and everything will be ok.

---

**EDIT:**

Well, better than this. Set up a `.s3ignore` file and just refer to it from the `sync` command:

```
s3cmd sync --exclude-from .s3ignore <local_dir> s3://<bucket>/
```

`.s3ignore` example:

```
.git
.git/*
.gitignore
node_modules
node_modules/*
*.swo
*.swp
*.pyo
*.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

I've do something similar. The key is to use --exclude before each pattern you want to match:

```
s3cmd -v --recursive --exclude ".ts" --exclude ".aac" --exclude "/thumbnails" put /var/www/folder s3://bucket/
```

Also I managed to use .ts without the wildcard symbol and it worked in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Other answers mention passing `--exclude <pattern>` for each pattern, and packing all patterns into a file to pass with `--exclude-from <file>`

Using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

You can also pack all patterns into a regular expression and pass it with the `--rexclude` option:

The Regex pattern for the question above: `".^\.*|._*|.~$*|.*.lock"`

`s3cmd sync --dry-run --verbose --delete-removed --rexclude ".^\.*|._*|.~$*|.*.lock" /home/user-folder s3://bucket-name/`